# MySQL: Why use UTF-8

Tags: sql, mysql, utf-8

This is an informative question rather than a how to. I am creating a database in MySQL that has the default encoding set to UTF-8. Now some of the primary keys are VARCHARs which take the primary key over the 1000 bit limit because each char using utf-8 is 3 bytes. Each key is 255 chars which brings the key to 1,530 bytes.

So if I would to change the encoding to Latin-1, the primary key would be under 1000 bytes and like magic the solution would work. But what is the advantage, if any, of using UTF-8? Why is it so popular?

Comment: I think the REAL question here is: 'Why use VARCHAR(255) as a primary key?'

Comment: @Mchl: No; the real question is: "How does 255 * 3 work out to 1530?"

Comment: He's probably trying to create UNIQUE composite index over two such fields (m-to-n relation table or something like this?)

Comment: Or even: if using latin-1 would be ok, how do you figure 3 bytes per character?

Comment: @araqnid: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html - when creating the key MySQL takes the most pessimistic variant to calculate the length.

Comment: @Mchl: That explains it; the most pessimistic approach for UTF-8 is actually, as shown by the math; 6 bytes per character. It must be said, tho'; that's not just pessimistic; that's laughably pessimistic. Even 3 bytes per character is somewhat unrealistic.

Comment: @Williham Totland: As explained in the link I posted above, MySQL uses RFC 3629 definition of UTF-8, which is at most 4B-per-character. Additionally, MySQL only supports 3B-per-character subset of this definition.

Comment: @Mchl: Which makes the whole 1530B thing even more odd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all; there seems to be a misconception or two about:

First; UTF-8 only uses multiple bytes for characters that require this; it's a VBR encoding.

Second; 255 multiplied by 3 isn't 1530; it's only half that.

Third; while keeping in mind that I'm not really a database expert per se; VARCHAR primary keys sounds like an extremely bad idea.

The reason for UTF-8s popularity; as has been stated by @Tomas Kohl; is that it can represent any Unicode character; but still allows representation of ASCII (U+127 and down) in single bytes.

If you have *any* international ambitions *whatsoever*; Never Don't Use UTF-8 (or N'DUUH! for short); or you **will** come to regret it.

**Hard**.

Comment: `Never Don't Use UTF-8`. I love it ;)

Comment: I use varchars as PK quite frequently (storing 32 character GUIDs). they are great when syncing different systems since the PK is always unique in all systems.

Comment: @jgauffin: As I said; I'm not an expert in Databases; but it really *does* sound like an extremely bad idea, at least most of the time; and at least and especially in MySQL.

Comment: @jgauffin: there's a difference between 32B long PK and 255B long PK.

Comment: @Williham: It's not that bad as it sounds. Some RDBS actually work better with PKs like that. For MySQL's InnoDB tables, the smaller PK the better (since the PK is included in all other indexes).

Comment: @mchl: Of course. @Williham seems to question varchar PK's in general, hence my comment to clarify that it isn't all bad.

Comment: Article about GUIDs: http://savvyduck.blogspot.com/2009/01/guids-as-primary-keys-or-how-to-walk.html

Comment: @WillihamTotland, I suggest you go over utf8everywhere.org. Perhaps it will make you rethink the "international ambitions" part :)

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: I'm sorry, what? I think you need to reread my decree: "Never Don't Use UTF-8!" There's a double negative in there. Meaning "Always Use UTF-8!". I admit the latter would be clearer, but it would be abbreviated "AUU!", which would just be stupid.

Comment: @WillihamTotland, humans are not so good with double negatives. A link to the manifesto is due though. You can contribute parts as well :)

Answer (score 8):

UTF-8 is popular because it brings sanity into handling non-English characters. It supports various non-English alphabets such as Arabic or Chinese. Should your application ever have the ambition to be localized into other languages, UTF-8 will definitely save you many headaches. Just search for 'character encoding' and you'll see how many of these there are.

Besides that I'd advise you do keep your primary keys as short as possible (and ideally numeric) for performance reasons.

Comment: +1 It doesn't even have to be anything as exotic as Chinese - just look at the 15-odd ISO-8859-x encodings, most of which are for European languages. Unicode (and its encoding UTF-8) is a ray of sanity in the character-encoding hell.

Answer (score 1):

General answer for general question:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages_and_disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a variable byte encoding with the number of bytes used for a character depending on that particular character.  In the case of characters that are in the 7-bit ASCII encoding (roughly English alphanumerics and some punctuation) only a single byte is used for the UTF-8 encoding (indeed it's the same byte).  If you're talking "latin1" and hence potentially thinking about a few accented characters then those will only be 2 byte UTF-8 characters.

So, when you say "each char using utf-8 is 3 bytes" you're not correct - unless you were talking about exotic characters not in latin1 anyway.

UTF-8 will let you use a wider range of characters in the future and, for English text, take up little (if any) additional space.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound right. If you are using characters present in the Latin-1 character set, then the characters would not use three bytes as UTF-8. Most characters would use a single byte, and maybe a few would use two bytes. I haven't checked, but I doubt that any character from the Latin-1 character set would use three bytes as UTF-8.

Unicode is useful when you need to store a wide variety of characters. You can for example store English, Chinese, Greek, Russian and Hebrew text in the same field, which is not possible with any single byte encoding.